# Using the xbox headset to talk to friends

Tags: xbox-360

My son has Xbox live.  When he chats to friends without playing an online game, does that use my internet data...does that require an internet connection to just talk to friends?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does.  Think about it; how is he managing to talk to his friends?  Xbox Live is an online area, and to talk to his friends, he's using the internet to do it.

Comment: looks like the parent just upped and deleted his account after asking the question... lol